# Редирект с помощью PHP с несуществующей страницы

Tags: php, redirect, редирект

Подскажите пожалуйста, как кодом PHP реализовать редирект с несуществующей страницы на главную (без использования .htaccess)?

Вот часть кода из индексного файла:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/') {
$Page = 'index';
$Module = 'index';
} else {
$URL_Path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$URL_Parts = explode('/', trim($URL_Path, ' /'));
$Page = array_shift($URL_Parts);
$Module = array_shift($URL_Parts);

//здесь массив $Module циклом разбиваем его на параметы. Например id2, id3 и так далее.
if (!empty($Module)) {
$Param = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($URL_Parts); $i++) {
$Param[$URL_Parts[$i]] = $URL_Parts[++$i];
}
}
} 



if ($Page == 'index') include('page/main.php');
```

Сейчас если посетитель переходит на несуществующую страницу, то он видит пустой белый экран, а нодо сделать редирект php-кодом на главную страницу

Comment: [Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477578), [Htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818694)

Comment: Слишком мало информации. Что для вас "не существующая страница"? Есть ли обработчик роутеров, обработчик ошибок? Редирект можно осуществить функцией header(), а именно: header('Location: http://www.example.com/');

Comment: исправил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Никаким.
Для того, чтобы запустился РНР код, **стрница с этим кодом должна существовать.**
Поэтому либо код будет запускаться только для существующих страниц, либо **надо настраивать веб сервер**, чтобы он запускал РНР для несуществующих страниц.

Comment: при чем здесь индексный файл? Перечитай ответ выше

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Comment: то есть ты спрашиваешь, как добавить else к твоему if-у?

Comment: после этого if-a идут ещё 200 таких if-oв

Comment: то есть ты спрашиваешь, как добавить else к двухсотому if-у?

Comment: Да)))))))))))))))

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо)    (переработал малость)